# UE4 class Operator bool() overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unreal-engine4

when I go through tutorial here [UE4 Basics](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/Tutorials/Components/4.)
I noticed that in **CollidingPawn.cpp**

A if statement is conditioned on a object `if (OurMovementComponent && ...){...}`

Which is declared and defined as

```
class UCollidingPawnMovementComponent* OurMovementComponent;

//...

class HOWTO_COMPONENTS_API UCollidingPawnMovementComponent : public UPawnMovementComponent
{/* ... */};
```

I think the class have a overloaded () operator, then I trace way back to all its [parents](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/UObject/index.html), but I could not find one, so I wonder what does the `if` statement check here, and how it's defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OurMovementComponent` is defined as a pointer. All pointers can be tested in conditionals, regardless of whether their pointee type has an overloaded `operator bool` or not.

There is no difference between fundamental types and class types when it comes to pointers to them.

The if statement is checking that the pointer is not null, likely before accessing the object it's supposed to point at, so as to avoid undefined behavior.